# Resizing a responsive DataTable is very slow, how can I speed it up?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable which has a couple of thousand records in it.

I have the responsive plugin for it, and the responsive option is enabled.

I also tried enabling the deferRender option, but this appeared to have no impact on the time taken.

When I resize the browser there is a delay of 1s - 2s. This happens in IE11, and MS Edge. The performance in chrome isn't fantastic, but at 0.5s it's tolerable.

[image: Profiler 1]

I am using custom ordering functions, but those functions are omitted for brevity. I'm fairly sure I know where the issue is, and it's not in them. I can provide them if required.

Here's my initialisation code:

```
this._dataTable = $("#listtable").DataTable({
    paging: true,
    responsive: true,
    deferRender: true,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        data: "thing.name"
    }, {
        title: "State 1",
        data: "state1",
        type: "state1",
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
            return this._renderState1(data, meta);
        }
    }, {
        title: "State 2",
        data: "state2",
        type: "state2",
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
            return this._renderState2(data, meta);
        }
    }]
});
```

I load the data by calling dataTable.row.add for each item, and then calling dataTable.draw at the end.

The performance issues occur after all the data has been successfully loaded, so I don't think it's to do with that.

Digging further in to the profiler information I found that it was the rendering of the rows that was the issue:

[image: Profiler 2]

By commenting out code in my custom render functions shown in the initalisation code, I found that the issue lay with finding the containing cell to set the background colour:

```
var cell = this._dataTable
    .cell({ row: meta.row, column: meta.col })
    .node();
```

Here's the rest of the code for setting the background colour:

```
var cellClass = this._getStateClass(state);
$(cell).addClass(cellClass);
```

If I comment the cell retrieval line out then the performance isn't amazing, but it is acceptable.

[image: Profiler 3]

So my question is how can I have a custom background colour for cells while maintaing the responsive performance?

A fast alternative to dataTable.cell would do, as would an alternative approach to setting the background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by removing the need to find the cell.

I put a class on the columns that removed the padding they have.

Style:

```
.cell-state1 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Configuration:

```
this._dataTable = $("#listtable").DataTable({
    paging: true,
    responsive: true,
    deferRender: true,
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        data: "thing.name"
    }, {
        title: "State1",
        data: "state1",
        type: "state1",
        className: "cell-state1",
        render: (data, type, row, meta) => {
            return this._renderState1(data, meta);
        }
    }]
});
```

Then I changed my render functions so they returned the content in a div which filled the cell, had the background colour, and added the padding back in.

Style:

```
.cell-state1-somestate {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Render Function:

```
function _renderState1 (state1) {
    var cssClass = _this._getState1CellClass(state1);
    var text = _this._getState1CellText(state1);
    var content = "<div class='" + cssClass + "'>" + text + "</div>";
    return content;
};
```

This left me with one final issue.

I have custom order functions, and now rather than being passed the text value they're passed the div containing the text value.

I used a little bit of jQuery to extract the text:

`var floodAlertSeverity = $(content).html();`.

It'd be nice if the order functions received the original data, rather than the rendered data, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with IE11 becoming extremely slow when resizing the browser window in responsive mode, which made for a pretty terrible user experience.

I don't have the time nor the expertise to fix the underlying issue (probably just IE11 being slow), but I came up with an elegant hack to work around the problem, which is basically to throttle the calls to the function that adjusts the column sizes.

The performance profiler in IE11 showed that calls to `_fnAdjustColumnSizing(oSettings);` were taking most of the CPU time, and the calls to this method are triggered by the `'resize.DT-YourTableNameHere'` event, so using a simple timer we can delay the call to this function until the user is done resizing the window:

```
var dtResizeTimer;
var allowPropagation = false;
$(window).on("resize.DT-visitsTable", function (event) {
    if (allowPropagation === false) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        clearTimeout(dtResizeTimer);
        dtResizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            allowPropagation = true;
            $(window).trigger("resize.DT-visitsTable");
        }, 100);
    } else {
        allowPropagation = false;
    }
});
```

Obviously you'll need to replace `visitsTable` with whatever `id` you gave to your `table` element.

It still takes a second for IE11 to  update the table after the user is done resizing, but at least the resizing itself is now smooth. There might be a better solution, but for now, this calms my frustration with IE11.